# How can I update (fetch?) a git repo to synchronize it with its master, while ignoring certain files?

Tags: git

I'm not sure if my nomenclature is correct so I'll try to describe what I did.

First I created a new repo on a remote server and used `git push origin master` to push my project there.  This is the branch/repo that I'd like to do all new work on.

Then I cloned this repo in a another folder on my local server. I want to use this branch as a live server where I can push to only when I'm sure that changes should be adopted.  Therefore I renamed to branch using: `git branch -m live`

Each of these branches needs to reference a different database, so they each have a config file with the apiKey and whatnot that needs to be specific to the branch.
Let's call this file config.js

My question is, how can I update all files in the live repo while ignoring a certain file?

Comment: different _database_?  Typically config files should not be versioned by Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply work with .gitignore. You can add a file ".gitignore" in your Repository-Folder and then you can add the files you want to ignore.
For your example you can navigate to your Repository-Folder with the Terminal an enter:

```
echo "config.js" >> .gitignore
```

For more information you can read: [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: `.gitignore` does not ignore tracked files. And if the config file on the server is untracked, there is no need to add it to gitignore. Moreover `.gitignore` file should be added to the repository so there is no need to replicate it in _every repository_

Comment: He did not mention that the the config file already tracked. If the config file on the server is untracked, there is a need to add it to gitignore. Because if he does not add it to the gitgnore, he have to check it at every commit, if he add the config to the commit or not.

Comment: I suppose that he is not going to commit from the server, but only pull. In this case the untracked config file won't cause any trouble